# Need help trying to get Postman to HTTPS POST some data

Tags: http-headers, http-post, postman

I'm trying to do an `HTTPS POST` with `Postman` and get a valid response with the Twitter OAuth 1.0 Sign In flow.

So the Twitter documents say I need to do an `HTTPS POST` with a specific `Authorization` header and I'll get a valid response.

Every time I try this, I get a `401 Not Authorized` result.

I'm using the sample twitter data [from this Twitter documentation page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token).

Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying...

[image]

In this example, the header *value* is

`OAuth oauth_nonce="K7ny27JTpKVsTgdyLdDfmQQWVLERj2zAK5BslRsqyw", oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%3A3005%2Ftwitter%2Fprocess_callback", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1300228849", oauth_consumer_key="OqEqJeafRSF11jBMStrZz", oauth_signature="Pc%2BMLdv028fxCErFyi8KXFM%2BddU%3D", oauth_version="1.0"`

(which is copied directly from that Twitter developer page).

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong, please?